# I don't know how to bootstrap Certbot on your operating system

Tags: openbsd, ssl, letsencrypt

I'm trying to add an Let's Encrypt cert on to my OpenBSD 6.0 using an `acme-client` and `certbot` - but both returns me:

```
# ./letsencrypt-auto certonly 
Sorry, I don't know how to bootstrap Certbot on your operating system!

You will need to bootstrap, configure virtualenv, and run pip install manually.
Please see https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contributing.html#prerequisites
for more info.

# ./certbot-auto 
Sorry, I don't know how to bootstrap Certbot on your operating system!
```

I have Python, `pip`, `virtualenv` installed, but still no luck.

Googling doesn't help, unfortunately.

What's wrong here? Have I missed some more packages?

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong here? Have I missed some more packages?

What's wrong is that the people who wrote the `letsencrypt-auto` script simply didn't include OpenBSD in the list of operating systems that that script supports.

Interestingly, the purpose of the script, if the parts for the other operating systems are anything to go by, is to install packages that you would otherwise be missing, using the operating systems' individual package tools.  Compare what it does for FreeBSD:

```
BootstrapFreeBsd() {
  $SUDO pkg install -Ay python py27-virtualenv augeas libffi
}
```

and for SmartOS:

```
BootstrapSmartOS() {
  pkgin update
  pkgin -y install 'gcc49' 'py27-augeas' 'py27-virtualenv'
}
```

For Debian it installs various packages with APT, with logic that basically tries to detect what the right package names are for different versions of Debian/Ubuntu and add some backport repositories.

So to fix this the script needs, at minimum, code that detects OpenBSD …

```
 elif uname | grep -iq OpenBSD ; then
    ExperimentalBootstrap "OpenBSD" BootstrapOpenBSD
```

… and a `BootstrapOpenBSD` function that installs the appropriate Python, GCC, augeas, and other packages using OpenBSD's old `pkg` toolset.  That, you will have to work out.

Comment: Cool investigation, had no time to check exactly script, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `certbot` from packages instead:

`pkg_add certbot`

For OpenBSD 6.0 - add `wxallowed` to `fstab`:

```
# cat /etc/fstab 
/dev/wd0a / ffs rw,wxallowed 1 1
```

To avoid an error "*Abort trap (core dumped)*".

Issue the certificate now:

```
# /usr/local/bin/certbot certonly --agree-tos --webroot -w /var/www/openbsdtest.example.org.ua/ -d openbsdtest.example.org.ua
Enter email address (used for urgent notices and lost key recovery) (Enter 'c'
to cancel):user@example.kiev.ua

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/openbsdtest.example.org.ua/fullchain.pem.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenBSD-CURRENT has its own ACME client in base now, acme-client(1)  ([cvs](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.sbin/acme-client/), [man](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/acme-client.1))
If you're using -STABLE I suggest downloading it from [github](https://github.com/kristapsdz/acme-client).